Errno 111 connection refused
I’m trying to write a program that transfers real-time video from a Seek thermal camera integrated with raspberry pi 3b+. The setup includes a flask server with websocket protocol and PC, where the raspberry pi acts as a client that captures and streams the real-time frames to the flask server, and the pc acts as a server that receives frames and applies a people detection algorithm using yolov8 AI model to them before displaying them. Unfortunately, when I try to run the code on both raspberry pi and pc I get connection refused errors, can someone help me, please?
The client code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from threading import Condition
import websocket
from seekcamera import (
    SeekCameraIOType,
    SeekCameraColorPalette,
    SeekCameraManager,
    SeekCameraManagerEvent,
    SeekCameraFrameFormat,
    SeekCamera,
    SeekFrame,
)

class Renderer:
    def _init_(self):
        self.busy = False
        self.frame = SeekFrame()
        self.camera = SeekCamera()
        self.frame_condition = Condition()
        self.first_frame = True

def on_frame(_camera, camera_frame, renderer):
    with renderer.frame_condition:
        renderer.frame = camera_frame.color_argb8888
        renderer.frame_condition.notify()

def on_event(camera, event_type, event_status, renderer):
    print("{}: {}".format(str(event_type), camera.chipid))

    if event_type == SeekCameraManagerEvent.CONNECT:
        if renderer.busy:
            return

        renderer.busy = True
        renderer.camera = camera

        renderer.first_frame = True

        camera.color_palette = SeekCameraColorPalette.WHITE_HOT

        camera.register_frame_available_callback(on_frame, renderer)
        camera.capture_session_start(SeekCameraFrameFormat.COLOR_ARGB8888)

    elif event_type == SeekCameraManagerEvent.DISCONNECT:
        if renderer.camera == camera:
            camera.capture_session_stop()
            renderer.camera = None
            renderer.frame = None
            renderer.busy = False

    elif event_type == SeekCameraManagerEvent.ERROR:
        print("{}: {}".format(str(event_status), camera.chipid))

def stream_video(renderer):
    ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/stream")
    while True:
        with renderer.frame_condition:
            renderer.frame_condition.wait(150.0 / 1000.0)
            frame = renderer.frame
            ws.send_binary(frame)
    ws.close()

if _name_ == "_main_":
    renderer = Renderer()
    with SeekCameraManager(SeekCameraIOType.USB) as manager:
        manager.register_event_callback(on_event, renderer)

        # Stream video to Flask server
        stream_video(renderer)

The server code:
from flask import Flask
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
import supervision as sv
#code for people detection on pc
app = Flask(name)

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    return 'Streaming...'

def processframe(frame):
    while True:
    # Convert frame to OpenCV format
        frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(frame, np.uint8), cv2.IMREADCOLOR)

    # Perform people detection using YOLOv8
        results = model(frame)[0]
        detections = sv.Detections.fromultralytics(results)

    # Annotate the frame
        labelannotator = sv.LabelAnnotator(
            border_radius=1,
            text_thickness=2,
            text_scale=1
         )
        annotated_frame = label_annotator.annotate(scene=frame, detections=detections)

    # Display the annotated frame
        cv2.imshow('Seek Thermal Camera', annotated_frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

if _name == "_main":
    import websocket

    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://192.168.1.8:8080/stream",
                                on_message=lambda ws, message: print(f"Received message: {message}"),
                                on_error=lambda ws, error: print(f"Error: {error}"),
                                on_close=lambda ws, close_status_code, close_reason: print(f"Connection closed: {close_status_code} - {close_reason}"))

    ws.run_forever()

I tried those codes as a client and server, and this error occurs Errno 111 connection refused.

Try to diagnose. Use netstat to see if the port is really open. Maybe change the host ip 192.168.1.8 and use 0.0.0.0. Use tools like nc to see if you can connect to that port or not. Check firewall settings (if any). You can clear up the setting with iptables -F.

@rakib_ when I tried to change the host ip of the raspberry pi to 0.0.0.0, it worked and stated to listen but still no output. when I use netcat and try to connect to the port, i get an error.

I was suggesting possible fix for your connection error issue, why your app doesn't talk, I'm not sure about that. As far as I know, websockets have their own way of communicating. You have to sort out that detail.
